# Recyclerview item jumps when it is focused

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, focus, selection

I'm building a Recyclerview populated with Textviews. The text must be selectable and I'm using the `TextView#setTextIsSelectable(true)` method to do that.
The problem is when I try to select the text of an item, it jumps to the top of the screen. I supose that the item is requesting the focus and this happen, but I don't want this behaviour, I want to select the text but without the RV jumping on each selection.

This is an example:

[image: RecyclerView jumps]